# I'm reviewing many first posts by leaving a comment. Is it OK?

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, best-practices

Well, as the title says, I'm reviewing some first questions with a comment saying basically ''improve your question by adding details (effort, context, etc.)'' and I'm a bit worried. In one hand, I think my behaviour is OK because the questions are ''good'', in the sense that they don't need to correct anything (MathJ is the most typical problem I see in first posts). But, on the other hand, they should be edited and I'm not doing it. Of course because I don't know the OP's context for the question, neither their efforts. I could also skip the review and give the problem to another user but I don't think that is a good solution.

So, is it Okey?

By the way, I hope this question wasn't duplicate. I have been reading some related questions and any of them seem to be like mine.

Comment: Is "what" okay??

Comment: Reviewing first posts with comments.

Comment: @jordan I guess you misunderstood; the comments are the *review action*.

Comment: There is nothing to do about reviewing others' review actions (there is no such a review queue in which one reviews others' *review actions,* @Lord).  The question is about reviewing new posts in the "new posts review queue", where one has the option of "no action necessary", "vote to close", "downvote,"  "flag,$ and or to comment.  The asker of this meta question has any of those options listed above.  If one sees comments others have left, one can agree and take action, or disagree and take no action.

Comment: @jordan And the OP is asking if their customary way of handling the First Posts queue (namely by means of posting comments encouraging context/effort/clarification/etc.)  is a good way of approaching said queue.

Comment: Got it, @Lord.  Thanks for the clarification.  I took "I'm reviewing many posts with a comment" to mean that the asker was reviewing new posts which had already received comments from others.  Your interpretation makes much more sense!

Answer (score 12):

It appears to me that this is definitely behaviour in the spirit of the review system. Therefore you are definitely not doing something wrong.

If this were the Low Quality queue or the Close Votes queue, I would have nothing to add.

---

However, I would like to add that the First Posts review queue is a bit special, in that it provides us with an opportunity to make the new contributor familiar with the etiquette and some of the best practices of Maths.SE.

For example, you could consider linking to the [FAQ entry for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), editing the title to be a precise formulation, editing tags, and generally anything listed out in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351). Just generally everything that helps the question be in a format that we appreciate, so that we teach the new contributor by example.

As a final general reference, I found the [Meta.SO guidelines for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/222340) (and in particular the [section about First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/222340)).